# Javascript + FB.api getting a list of FB pages

Tags: javascript, facebook, json

I have a Json object return from my FB.api but I have difficulty in fetching the data components in it, basically I just need the 'name' and 'accesstoken' every individual from 'data', tried several ways from a few examples but still can't get it. Can anybody help. Thanks.

```
if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me/accounts', function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    });
                }
```

I can see the data from firebug like this from the log result:

```
data


[Object { name=

"Test Company"

,  access_token=

"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

,  category=

"Travel/leisure"

,  more...}, Object { name=

"Some Page"

,  access_token=

"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

,  category=

"Computers/technology"

,  more...}, Object { name=

"Something"

,  access_token=

"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

,  category=

"App page"

,  more...}, 40 more...]


paging
    Object { next=

"https://graph.facebook....fter_id=68468454846654"

}
```

Comment: Do you have more samples of your code - it could be you need to wrap your response in a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try iterating over data?

```
for (i in data){
   console.log(data[i]);
   console.log(data[i].access_token);
}
```